# Stripping file extensions from file names

Tags: excel, excel-formula, bioinformatics

I have a Excel spreadsheet in which one column is for accession numbers. While importing the accession numbers, the person imported the filenames instead of just numbers. So now the accession 'numbers' look like:

> SRA002989.sra
>   SRA002986.sra
>   ....

Is there a way to strip off the extensions and just keep the first part like `SRA002989`,  `SRA002986` etc.?

Comment: Select the column containg the file names, then from the data menu, click text to columns. Select . as a separator.

Comment: it looks like you're trying to do bioinformatics in excel... https://twitter.com/tim_yates/status/367297797709504513

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the SUBSTITUTE() function.  If your data is in Column A, the following will work and can be copied around as necessary.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".sra","")
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach would be to select the column, press CTRL + H for search and replace and to search for ".sra" and replace it with an empty value (just leave the second field empty).